Custom Permission Mixin Django Rest Framework
I am trying to create a custom mixim that handles additional permission checks in my views.
This is what I have tried:
    class ProfilePermissionsRequiredMixin:
    required_permissions = []

    def get_required_permissions(self):
        return self.required_permissions

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if the user is authenticated
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            raise PermissionDenied("You must be logged in to access this resource.")

        # Get the user's profile
        profile = request.user.profile

        # Check if the profile has all the required permissions
        if all(profile.has_perm(perm) for perm in self.get_required_permissions()):
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # Return 403 Forbidden if any permission check fails
        raise PermissionDenied("You do not have permission to access this resource.")

The issue here is that the request that I get is not authenticated. I use a custom authentication class and it is apparently not applied in the despatch.
What can I do to fix this?

There are two parts of the drf APIView dispatch method that are related to authentication.
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        -----------------------------------------------------------
        request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        -----------------------------------------------------------
        self.request = request
        self.headers = self.default_response_headers  # deprecate?

        try:
            --------------------------------------
            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
            --------------------------------------   
            # Get the appropriate handler method
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc)

        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response

The first is to invoke the initialize_request method, where the authentication_classes set in View are imported and created.
The following is the invocation of the initial method, which calls the perform_authentication method, a method that performs a practical authentication process.
  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if the user is authenticated
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            raise PermissionDenied("You must be logged in to access this resource.")

        # Get the user's profile
        profile = request.user.profile

        # Check if the profile has all the required permissions
        if all(profile.has_perm(perm) for perm in self.get_required_permissions()):
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # Return 403 Forbidden if any permission check fails
        raise PermissionDenied("You do not have permission to access this resource.")

In your dispatch method, the part where the authentication process proceeds is estimated to be super(). dispatch().
I presume that your intention is to add a require_permission verification process.
In DRF APIView, the verification and authentication process takes place in the initial method.
That's why I recommend overriding the initial method to add an additional verification process.
    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super.initial(requset, *args, **kwargs)
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            raise PermissionDenied("You must be logged in to access this resource.")

        # Get the user's profile
        profile = request.user.profile

        # Check if the profile has all the required permissions
        if all(profile.has_perm(perm) for perm in self.get_required_permissions()):
            return 

        # Return 403 Forbidden if any permission check fails
        raise PermissionDenied("You do not have permission to access this resource.")
    


This indeed fixes my issues. Is this explained in the docs? I couldnt find any info about it. I might have missed it, may you point me to where its explained?
And one more issue I faced is that the raise PermissionDenied causes a 500 crash, why is that? Returning an Httpresponse fixes this but I would like to raise the error a DRF's exceptions.

super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) --> Estimated that the would call APIView's dispatch method. I did not find a detailed description of the authentication process in the drf official document. I understood the authentication process through the source code in APIView. I think I'll have to see more of your source code for the 500-error-related part.

I was testing this and it is not really working. Whats happening is when a user doesnt have permission in a view, the Httresponse is returned, but the view is still executed. I guess the mixin is letting the view finish and then is checking the permissions. This is a major issue for me.

how about you use the initial method instead of the dispatch method? I think it would be better to add the required_permission step to the initial method. I'll attach it to the response.
